# "You being an Asian does not / don't know this"

Tags: word-usage

> It’s a shame that you being an Asian **does not** know this

I somehow have the feeling that this doesn't sound right! Particularly the last  *does not know this* part. Should it be

> It's a shame that you being an Asian **don't** know this?

Comment: Apart from the verb, we do not normally say that someone is _an_ Asian (or a European, or an African), just that they are Asian/European/African. The noun (with the article) is only used when it refers to countries; for continents, the adjective is preferred.

Comment: Just as a suggestion, this sentence doesn't sound like natural English. Something more common would be, "As an Asian, you should know this."

Comment: The participle construction is too literary for spoken English.

Comment: As an aside, the sentence “You being (an) Asian does not know this” is perfectly grammatical, but it is utter nonsense. It’s supposed to mean that ‘you’ are Asian and as such do not know something; but what it really means is that _the fact that ‘you’ are Asian_ does not know something, and that is tautological nonsense: facts are not capable of knowing anything, since they’re not sentient beings. @rogermue The participle construction is perfectly common in spoken English; it just doesn’t fit very well in this particular sentence.

Answer (score 7):

It may become more apparent if you move the 'you' to the other side of 'being an Asian,' making the sentence:

> It's a shame that, being an Asian, you does not know this.

'You does' should become 'you do,' making the sentence:

> It's a shame that, being an Asian, you do not know this."

Answer (score 4):

No. I think you want:

"it's a shame that you, being (an) Asian, do not (/don't) know this"

Answer (score 1):

Instead of 'being an Asian', the term 'as an Asian' might work well.

> It’s a shame that as an Asian, you do not know this.

You'd probably be better off totally rearranging the sentence to make it clearer.

> It's a shame that an Asian like you does not know this.

or

> It's a shame that an Asian such as you does not know this.